# When is a SQLite Database for an Android application deleted?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I do web dev, and the information in the database is removed if I do it myself, but what about with Android? Will that information be deleted if I was to perform a factory reset on the phone? Is the only way to delete the database is ny removing the app from the phone?

Comment: `Will that information be deleted if I was to perform a factory reset on the phone? Is the only way to delete the database is ny removing the app from the phone?` Of course it will. No it's not the only way.

Answer (score 1):

> Will that information be deleted if I was to perform a factory reset on the phone?

If the database is in its normal spot ([internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)), then a factory reset should prevent further access to the data. Somebody with sufficient forensic tools can probably still get at it, though, unless the user had their device set up with full-disk encryption.

> Is the only way to delete the database is ny removing the app from the phone?

You, as a developer, can delete the database by [calling `deleteDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#deleteDatabase%28java.io.File%29).

The user can also click the "Clear Data" button on your app's page in Settings. This is uncommon but can happen. From the standpoint of your app, the result is very similar to what you would see if the user uninstalled and reinstalled your app.

Comment: Thank you for this. There were some other answers here but they got deleted. I will ask you and we will go from there. If I use this method to save information the user puts in, I will not need to create a login/register for the user. Also, can this information (the database file) be saved to google using their backup manager / cloud?

Comment: @AndroidDevNoob: "can this information (the database file) be saved to google using their backup manager / cloud?" -- yes. In fact, in the M Developer Preview, it will be backed up by default, for users who opt into backing up their Android apps in general.

Comment: Well then that's great news. So if I develop this application with internal sqlite, will it be automatically backed up if that device goes to M? Also, if I back up with that service now, would I be able to remove that feature? I'm trying to have it so the user will not lose their info if they do a hard reset on the device.

Comment: @AndroidDevNoob: "So if I develop this application with internal sqlite, will it be automatically backed up if that device goes to M?" -- if the user agrees to such backups. "would I be able to remove that feature?" -- your app optionally can control what gets backed up.

Comment: Will that also allow the user to sync across devices? Two devices, no matter which device u enter the info on, it'll show in the other?

Comment: That seems silly. The only true way to do that would be with mysql and php?

Comment: @AndroidDevNoob: "The only true way to do that would be with mysql and php?" -- I certainly wouldn't use those. However, you do have to implement data synchronization yourself, if that is what you mean. "That seems silly" -- data synchronization across multiple copies, with only intermittent connectivity, is not an easy problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Currently I have a login and register using php and sql. The php takes the info from the java fields and puts them in the dB. Then fetches it for login. If most of the work is done in java and then httpposts to sql, is that bad? Perhaps we can email? If your willing. Ginsberg.m (at) gmail